# Wordpress custom post type permalink parent/child but different types

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, permalinks

In wordpress I created 2 custom post types: company and offer
offers are linked to companies with a customfield called companyname.

So if an offer called 'My offer' is linked to Company 'ACME', both posttype contain a customfield called 'companyname' with value of ACME.So far no problem.

I registered both custom posttypes with a default slug 'company' and 'offer'

The shop permalink url is now: www.mywebsite.nl/company/acme/
The offer permalink url is now: www.mywebsite.nl/offer/my-offer/

What I want is the offer permalink is changed to www.mywebsite.nl/company/acme/my-offer/

I searched a lot through filters/action/hooks (and stackoverflow), but I cannot find a solution. I even tried to make the post-types hierarchical, but in an 'offer' posttype I cannot make a 'company' posttype the parent.

How can get the url structure I need?

Answer (score 0):

There's two things you need to solve.

First, you need the url for the offers to be changed to your new form. This is done by specifying a slug that you can modify for each of the offers.

When registering the post type, add a variable to the slug:

```
    // add modified 
    register_post_type('company_offer_type',array(
    ...
       'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => 'company/%company%'
        ),
    ));

    // filter to rewrite slug
    add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'postTypeLink', 10, 2);
    function postTypeLink($link, $post)
    {
        if (get_post_type($post) === 'company_offer_type') {
            $company = // get company from $post
            $link = str_replace('%company%', $company, $link);
        }
        return $link;
    }
```

Second, you want wordpress to redirect incoming url requests to this post. Do this by adding a rewrite rule on the init action:

```
    // add rewrite rule for custom type
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'company/(.*)/(.*)',
        'index.php?post_type=company_offer_type&name=$matches[2]',
        'top'
    );
```

Here are two articles with more info:

http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/the-rewrite-api-the-basics--wp-25474

http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/the-rewrite-api-post-types-taxonomies--wp-25488

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I'll give this a try. However I don't think it wil work. I tried something similar. I noticed that a slash in the slug is removed. So 'slug' => 'company/%company%' became 'slug' => 'company-%company%' in a previous test.